# D'Alembert Solution Formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a test tomorrow and the only thing holding me back from getting a good grade is D'Alembert formula for boundary conditions. I have this example that I am trying to figure out.

> Find $u(\frac{6}{5a},\frac12)$ if $u$ solves $$u_{tt}=a^2u_{xx}, \ 0<x<1, t>0$$ $$u(0,x)=1, \ u_t(0,x)=-a, \ 0\le x\le 1$$ $$u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0, \ t\ge0.$$

I can use D’Alembert formula, with odd extension, which is $$u(t,x)=\frac12 \left[ \tilde{f}(x+ct)+\tilde{f}(x-ct) \right]+\frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+ct}_{x-ct}\tilde{g}(s)ds.$$

Where $$\tilde{f}(y) =\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad 0<y<1\\
    -1 & \quad -1<y<0\\ \text{periodic with period 2}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Therefore, $$u(\frac{6}{5a},\frac12)=\frac12 \left[\tilde{f}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac65)+\tilde{f}(\frac12-\frac65)\right]+\frac{1}{2a}\int^{\frac12+\frac65}_{\frac12-\frac65}\tilde{g}(y)dy.$$

But this is were I am stuck. How will I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tilde{f}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{5}\right) = \tilde{f}\left(\frac{17}{10}\right) = \tilde{f}\left(\frac{17}{10}-2\right)=\tilde{f}\left(-\frac{3}{10}\right)=-1$$

Similarly, $~~\tilde{f}(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}) = -1$.

$$\tilde{g}(y) = -a~~\text{, so }~~\int_{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}}\tilde{g}(y)~dy = \int_{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{5}}-a~dy = -\frac{12}{5}a$$

Using your formula,

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\tilde{f}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{5}\right)+\tilde{f}\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}\right)\right] + \frac{1}{2a}\int_{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{5}}\tilde{g}(y)~dy$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\left[(-1)+(-1)\right] + \frac{1}{2a}\left(-\frac{12}{5}a\right)$$

$$= -1 -\frac{6}{5}$$

$$ = -\frac{11}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you! How did get $-1$ in your first line? And $~~\tilde{f}(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}) = -1$? Also, why is $g(y)=-a$?

Comment: $f$ is the initial position data, and $g$ is the initial velocity. In the first line I used the periodicity of $f$ to get a number between -1 and 1.

Comment: I see thanks for clarifying! And since we subtracted from the period shouldn't our integral be $\int^{-\frac{3}{10}}_{\frac{13}{10}}$?

Comment: No. Another way to think about it is: since $f$ is periodic with period 2, $f(x)=-1$ for $1<x<2$, $f(x)=1$ for $2<x<3$, $f(x)=-1$ for $3<x<4$, etc. Since 17/10 is between 1 and 2, we get -1.

Comment: So the integral $\int_{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{5}}$ should not be changed as well? I was thinking since we subtracted the period for $f(y)$ shouldn't that affect the integral as well?

Comment: We only subtracted the period to figure out the value at 17/10. This doesn't change anything else about the problem. Look at my previous comment. You could have found f(17/10) without subtracting anything. Since f is periodic f(17/10) = f(-3/10) = f(-23/10) = f(-43/10) = ...

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your test!